# Probability that coin tossing game terminates

Tags: probability, expected-value

> A player tosses a fair coin. He receives \$1 for each head and loses \$1 for each tail. The player quits when his position is +\$1. What's the probability that the game terminates? What is the expected winnings of the game?

Is this a trick question? The probability that the game *eventually* terminates should be 1? This then makes the second question moot, because the expected winning would just be 1. I suspect I may be misunderstanding something because I don't think this question is intended to be this simple or for it to be a trick question.

The problem does not state whether the game can continue indefinitely or if there's a set number of tosses. If it can continue indefinitely, then I think my solution applies. If there's a fixed number of tosses, then it's more complicated.

---

Assuming there's a fixed number of tosses, say, $n$, then I think we need to check for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ such that the player has a net positive \$1.

Comment: I don't think it's a trick question. I think you are right that the probability the game eventually terminates is $1$. But it's not obvious, to me at least, that the expected winnings is 1.

Comment: @AdamRubinson If the game terminates, then it'll terminate when that person has a net positive of \$1, right? So the expected winnings should just be 1?

Comment: Not necessarily. There's an infinite number of ways of getting to 1. And there's an infinite number of ways of not getting to 1, and many of the ways of not getting to 1 involve diverging to -infinity, which brings down the value of the expected winnings...

Comment: @AdamRubinson But isn't the problem asking for the expected winnings after the game terminates? So we're conditioning on the game terminating, which means we only consider the cases where we net \$1? That's the way I interpreted it originally at least.

Comment: No: if the game doesn't terminate he has still played a game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected value of the game **must be** $(0)$, because the expected value of each coin toss is $(0)$.

Suppose that there is a 2nd condition that the game must end after $n$ coin tosses, if $(+1)$ is never achieved.  There is some small chance that the coin tosser loses a lot of money.

As $n \to \infty$, the chance of losing goes to $0$, and if a loss is sustained, there is some chance that the loss is *considerable*.

What is happening is that there is a smaller and smaller chance of losing a *considerable amount of money*.

Further, as $n \to \infty$, the chance of ending up a $+1$ winner *approaches* but never equals certainty.

---

It's important to remember that infinity is not a number, but rather a symbol for unbounded growth.  Therefore, you can never have an infinite number of coin tosses.

Comment: This is the part I'm confused about and I discussed it in the comments under my OP. Isn't this game defined as terminating when we net +\$1, and we are asked to find the expected earnings when the game *terminates*?

Comment: @roulette01 See the extra addition that I just made at the end of my answer.  The premise of an infinite number of coin tosses is not tenable, because infinity is not a number.  All that you can do, is find the limit as $n \to \infty$ that you end up a +1 winner.  It will never be **certain** that you end up a +1 winner.  Another way of saying the same thing is that the premise, as stated, is **nonsensical.**

Comment: Hmm, I see. But why would this mean the expected earning is zero, instead of some other number?

Comment: @roulette01 Re-read the first part of my answer.  Then, post another comment, if you still have a question.

Comment: If there wasn't a termination condition that we terminate when we're up 1, then I think the expectation is zero. It's just a symmetric random walk and the expectation is zero after any number of steps. The issue is we have this termination conditoin that makes me think the expectation is no longer zero.

Comment: @roulette01 Saying that you have a positive expectation because you have an infinite number of coin tosses, if necessary is equivalent to saying that you have a positive expectation because $(2 +2) = 3,$ or more precisely because $(2 + 2) = $ a giraffe.

Comment: I wrote it out for a few examples with $n=3, n=5$, and I always get an expectation of zero. Still a bit over my head though.

Comment: @roulette01 The coin doesn't think.  Each coin toss by itself has a zero expectation.  That is conclusive.  If $f(x) = 0,$ for all $x$, then the $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n) = 0.$

Comment: If the number of tosses $n$ is bounded, then the probability of terminating would monotonically increase from 0.5  to 1 as $n \rightarrow \infty$ right? When we have $n=1$, it is obvious that the probability of terminating is 0.5.

Comment: @roulette01 Yes: in fact, please re-read my answer.  By the way, if this concept was **not** confusing to non-mathematicians, Las Vegas would not be as profitable.

Comment: Yeah I read that part of your answer. If we instead asked the question "What is the probability of winning with exactly $n$ tosses?" Then I think in this situation, when $n$ is even, the probability of winning is zero. When $n$ is odd, we have the monotonic increase as n increases?

Comment: @roulette01 No, as $n \to \infty$ the chance of ending up $+1$ is strictly increasing.  The reason that your symettry argument fails, is that if you get to $+1$ you stop, where if you get to $-1$, you do **not** stop, so you might still recover and get to $+1.$

Comment: But how would you win with exactly 2 tosses? You can win with 1 toss, but it's not possible with 2 tosses? In order to get to 2 tosses, you must toss a tail on the first toss, and then the second toss is either a head or tail, so it's not possible to go up 1 with exactly 2 tosses? The only possibilities with exactly 2 tosses is you're down 2 or you broke even.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122431/discussion-between-user2661923-and-roulette01).